# Error: Unable to access jarfile in docker-compose

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

Below is my `docker-compose.yml`, which is pretty much simple.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  book-api:
    image: openjdk:11
    container_name: book-api
    volumes:
      - ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/bookapi.jar
    command: ["java","-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8080","-Dspring.profiles.active=local","-jar","bookapi.jar"]
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

But when I do `docker-compose up`, I get the below error:

```
Creating book-api ... done
Attaching to book-api
book-api    | Error: Unable to access jarfile bookapi.jar
book-api exited with code 1
```

I don't see an error with mounting volumes. jar file (`target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`) is created and is in the correct location.
[image]

I also tried to change `command` to below, thinking that was causing issue:

```
["java","-jar","bookapi.jar"]
```

But I'm getting the same error. I'm running `docker-compose` on mac.

To troubleshoot the issue, I changed the command to check the file paths, permissions etc.

```
command: >
      sh -c "ls -l && pwd && java -jar bookapi.jar"
```

And then I see below results:

```
rahulraj@my-pc % docker-compose up
Starting book-api ... done
Attaching to book-api
book-api    | total 46764
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Jun 23 15:20 bin
book-api    | -rwxrwxrwx   1 root root 47821378 Jun 27 15:25 bookapi.jar
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Mar 19 13:46 boot
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   5 root root      340 Jun 28 06:50 dev
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Jun 28 06:48 etc
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Mar 19 13:46 home
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Jun 22 00:00 lib
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Jun 22 00:00 media
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Jun 22 00:00 mnt
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Jun 22 00:00 opt
book-api    | dr-xr-xr-x 183 root root        0 Jun 28 06:50 proc
book-api    | drwx------   1 root root     4096 Jun 23 15:21 root
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   3 root root     4096 Jun 22 00:00 run
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Jun 23 01:11 sbin
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Jun 22 00:00 srv
book-api    | dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root        0 Jun 28 06:50 sys
book-api    | drwxrwxrwt   1 root root     4096 Jun 23 15:21 tmp
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Jun 22 00:00 usr
book-api    | drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     4096 Jun 22 00:00 var
book-api    | /
book-api    | Error: Unable to access jarfile bookapi.jar
book-api exited with code 1
```

Seems like the `jar` file is having full permissions, current working directory is `/` and path of `jar` file is `/bookapi.jar`. But the command `java -jar /bookapi.jar` is failing with the above mentioned error. I tried with `java -jar bookapi.jar` too.

Am I doing something wrong here? Kindly suggest. Thanks!

Comment: What is your working directory when you execute the command? Is it `/` or a different path? (I assume the latter)

Comment: This setup doesn't seem like it should really require Docker.  (You're not using any of Docker's features; this setup is using an isolation system just to try to run a prepackaged language runtime against code that lives on your host system.)  Can you install a JVM locally using Homebrew or another similar tool instead?

Comment: @knittl I'm executing `docker-compose` from project root, where both `/target` folder and `docker-compose.yml;` are present.

Comment: @DavidMaze I haven't added other details from my `docker-compose` file here. Whether I add them or not, I get the same error. So, I added only what is required here. Do you know why `docker-compsoe` throws out this error?

Comment: @knittl
The error is when docker execute the `command`, not during mapping the volume.

Comment: @RahulRaj yes and the command is executed in a directory. Since you are referring to your jar file by relative path, your docker container needs to change to the correct directory before running your executable. You could also try specifying the jar file as absolute path: `java -jar /bookapi.jar`

Comment: @knittl
check this out -> https://i.imgur.com/cIeVRh6.png
This screenshot will give you much better clarity. Can you point out where exactly it is going wrong? I tried all permutations and combinations of path, but still the same error. I'm not sure which path it is actually being copied in the docker.

Comment: @knittl
The error message will just get updated to new path that we give in the command. So`java -jar /bookapi.jar` will get error `Unable to access jarfile /bookapi.jar`. When I do `java -jar bookapi.jar`, I get `Unable to access jarfile bookapi.jar` error. 

Is there a way to do `ls -a` while executing docker compose? I get `operation not permitted` if I try to add that in `command`.

Comment: @RahulRaj Replace your command: line with `command: ["ls","-l", "bookapi.jar"]`, `command: ["pwd"]`, or `command: ["ls", "-la"]`

Comment: @knittl
apparently, I did the above and here are the results:
https://i.imgur.com/FjRwZtc.png

I'm not sure if this is an issue with execution permission?

Comment: @RahulRaj yes, could be a permission issue. Please don't post images of text, edit your question to include all the relevant details.

Comment: @knittl
I will add update the post. btw I gave full permission to the jar file, but I get the same error.     `-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root 47821378 Jun 27 15:25 bookapi.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it was not working while using only `docker-compose.yml`. So, the above mentioned issue is still a mystery unresolved, however I changed the docker config to below and no more issues observed.

1. Created a docker image of the application with a `Dockerfile`

   ```
   From openjdk:11
   copy ./target/app.jar app.jar
   CMD ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
   ```

   and then `docker image build -t book-api .`
2. Modified `docker-compose.yml` as below:

   ```
   services:
       book-api:
         image: book-api
         container_name: book-api
         ports:
            - "8080:8080"
   ```

   and then `docker-compose up` worked without any issues and container is up and running.

Thank you @knittl for your inputs.